# Reduce Mapbox map size without cropping

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I would like to keep my Mapbox map content always fully visible, no matter the container's size.
But when the map is very small, the map is getting cropped.

Here is an example of what I have https://codepen.io/eddydg/pen/BmReEm

When you reduce the page width, it will also reduce the map container height to keep its size ratio. But the map won't zoom out further to keep all layers visible.

```js
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8',
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  map.zoomTo(0);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: thin black solid;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  height: 400px;
}

.map-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vw; /* 100% */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.mapbox.com/help/data/codepen-token.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.12.2/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.12.2/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="map-wrapper">
      <div id='map'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** this seems to have been fixed in Mapbox GL js v1.6.0-beta.1

Actually [this seems to be a bug](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3055) that happens when the viewport is smaller than 512px.
It's pretty old and still not fixed. So as a workaround, I ended up using a rollover effect on the map:

- Mouse out of the map: increase the map size (>=512px to see the whole map) and [`scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) it back to the original size with CSS. You will have the whole map visible (whatever its size) but all the interactions will be shifted.
- Mouse over the map: back to the origin size and `scale(1)` so the map will be cropped, but you will be able to properly interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem here is that in order for the map to be resized in order to keep everything in view at the tiny size in question, it would have to zoom out beyond zoom level 0. Which isn't possible. Possibly you could hack something using CSS to scale the actual rendered map with pixel ratios or something.

Comment: I tried to scale in CSS with `transform: scale(0.5)`, but then the map is completely offsetted: the mouse position doesn't match the feature underneath.
Maybe the scaling needs to be done directly in the canvas but `canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl')` doesn't seem to have a simple scale() method.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't really surprise me. Might require quite a bit of hacking to make something workable.